# Java Load Exception Namespace Method handler

Tags: java, fxml

Hello I am trying to build a bank UI with scene builder and fxml. However, when I try to load the second screen, the `#bro` function gives me an error. When I eliminate the function, the program opens up the second screen without any error.

This is the full error I get:

```
Executing D:\ATM4\dist\run1255295863\ATM4.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre/bin/java
Iun 19, 2015 5:09:35 PM atm4.Baza inlocuiesteScena
SEVERE: null

javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#bro', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
file:/D:/ATM4/dist/run1255295863/ATM4.jar!/atm4/doi.fxml:19
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:606)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:766)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2827)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2536)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2413)
    at atm4.Baza.inlocuiesteScena(Baza.java:57)
    at atm4.Baza.incarcDoi(Baza.java:31)
    at atm4.UnuController.intra(UnuController.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3767)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$104/1416396302.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**This is the main class**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package atm4;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Mnezo
 */
public class Baza extends Application {

    Stage stage;

    public void incarcUnu() {
        UnuController atmctrl = (UnuController) inlocuiesteScena("unu.fxml");
        atmctrl.setBaza(this);
    }
      public void incarcDoi() {
        UnuController atmctrl = (UnuController) inlocuiesteScena("doi.fxml");
        atmctrl.setBaza(this);
    }
       public void incarcTrei() {
        UnuController atmctrl = (UnuController) inlocuiesteScena("trei.fxml");
        atmctrl.setBaza(this);
    }
    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            stage = primaryStage;
            stage.setTitle("ATM");

            UnuController atmctrl = (UnuController) inlocuiesteScena("unu.fxml");
            atmctrl.setBaza(this);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Initializable inlocuiesteScena(String fxml) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource(fxml));
        AnchorPane container;
        try {
            container = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(container);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.sizeToScene();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Baza.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return (Initializable) loader.getController();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

In the second screen fxml I get this error Handler Method not found, here is the code, and bro is underlined with red:

```
 <Button fx:id="romana" layoutX="468.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#bro" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="49.0" />
```

Screen one controller:

```
package atm4;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class UnuController implements Initializable {
    private Baza baza;
    @FXML
    private ImageView im1;

    public void setBaza(Baza baza) {
        this.baza = baza;
    }



    @FXML
    private Rectangle welcome;

    void fff96f(ActionEvent event) {

    }



      @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }  

    @FXML
    private void intra(MouseEvent event) {
        baza.incarcDoi();
    }


}
```

Screen Two controller:

```
package atm4;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.LoadException;

public class DoiController implements Initializable {
    private Baza baza;

    public void setBaza(Baza baza) {
        this.baza = baza;
    }

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    public Button romana;

    @FXML
    private Button engl;

    @FXML
    private Button magh;

    @FXML
    private Button fran;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle welcome;

    @FXML
    void fff96f(ActionEvent event) {

    }



 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }  
     @FXML
   private void bro(ActionEvent event) {
       // baza.incarcTrei();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for the bro method?

Comment: <Button fx:id="romana" layoutX="468.0" layoutY="128.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#bro" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="49.0" /> and the bro method is in screen two controller

Answer (score 0):

Probably the java class selected in "fx:controller" are not correct. Check if you choose the correct java class, in your case DoiController. Could be that the action #bro are in your fxml file, but are not in the DoiController.